# How to convert a single column file into a single row?

Tags: text-processing, awk, perl

I would like to convert my one colum of many rows into one line:

example :

```
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
4
```

and I want :

```
11111222334
```

any suggestion please?

Comment: Related post on stackoverflow : http://stackoverflow.com/q/3134791/3701431

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try echoing the command and sendig the output to a new file.

```
$ echo $(cat file) >> rows.txt
```

To prevent whitespaces between each line you can use sed in the same line

```
$ echo $(cat file) | sed 's/ //g' >> rows.txt
```

Comment: This will have strange results if the file contains characters in `\[*?`. It'll also strip off all whitespace, which may or may not (probably not) have been desired.

Comment: @Gilles for the example given, I think this will work while the OP is not specifying the characters you mentioned, what do you think?

Answer (score 6):

paste:

```
$ paste -s -d "" file
11111222334
```

squeeze all lines together with no delimiter.

or these solutions that delete even the trailing newline

```
perl -pe chomp file
awk -v ORS="" 1 file
```

Answer (score 4):

You could delete all newline characters with `tr`:

```
tr -d \\n <infile
```

Note there's no trailing newline character in the output so, if that's needed (e.g. to redirect to another file):

```
{ tr -d \\n <infile; printf \\n; } >outfile
```

If, instead, you need the fields separated by a space you could run:

```
row=$(tr \\n \   <infile)
printf %s\\n "${row%?}" >outfile
```

though [`paste`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233102) really shines here...